# Is there a Prāyaścitta for not fasting on Rāma-navamī́?

Tags: rama, festivals, skanda-purana

The Agastya-saṁhitā́ mentions not fasting on Rāma-navamī́ will result in being cooked in hell.

> That wretched man who eats food on Rama- navami suffers torments in
> the terrible hells called Kumbhīpāka." -
> P. V. Kane Translation

[image]

Is there a Prāyaścitta mentioned anywhere in any scripture for failing to fast on Rāma-navamī́?